# Can int values reset if too much is loaded at once?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, int, qstring

In my C++ project, I have some int values (I am following two of them specifically). These values are input when the user loads a file. Their values (should) never change throughout the entire program.

Later on in my program, I load about 30 MB of data into around 3000 QString variables (4 arrays). It seems that around a certain number of strings loaded, my int values reset to zero. I only use them at the beginning and end of my program.

I didn't put any source code simply because my program is huge and I don't feel comfortable putting all the source code on the web.

So my question is, is it possible for some variables to be "reset" because new variables are being filled? I get no errors or freezing like I would expect from bad allocation. This has got me completely puzzled.

Thanks for your time :)

EDIT:
Here is the exact spot I notice my int values get reset. Btw, All this code worked when editing a smaller amount of files.

```
//These loops input 2916 files each around 10kb. They are loaded into 4 QString arrays.
if(OregionBR != "Null")
{
    for(int z=0; z <=26; z++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x <=26; x++)
        {
            temp_hex = OregionBR.mid((z*256)+(x*8), 6);
            if(temp_hex != "000000")
            {
                temp_hex.append("000");
                HexToInt(temp_hex, temp_int);
                //Here, the files are input.
                Input("stuff\\regions\\xbox_chunks\\br\\" + QString::number(temp_int) + ".dat", temp_chunk);

                //... minor file changes

                //The file is then loaded into the array
                OBRChunks[(zPos*27) + xPos] = temp_chunk;

                //... minor file changes
            }
        }
    }
}
//level_ptr is my int value. This number is around 150,000
QMessageBox::information(this, "test", QString::number(level_ptr));
if(OregionBL != "Null")
{
    for(int z=0; z <=26; z++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x <=26; x++)
        {
            temp_hex = OregionBL.mid((z*256)+(x*8)+40, 6);
            if(temp_hex != "000000")
            {
                temp_hex.append("000");
                HexToInt(temp_hex, temp_int);
                Input("stuff\\regions\\xbox_chunks\\bl\\" + QString::number(temp_int) + ".dat", temp_chunk);

                //... minor file changes

                OBLChunks[(zPos*27) + xPos] = temp_chunk;

                //... minor file changes
            }
        }
    }
}
//level_ptr is my int value. This number is around 150,000
QMessageBox::information(this, "test", QString::number(level_ptr));
if(OregionTR != "Null")
{
    for(int z=0; z <=26; z++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x <=26; x++)
        {
            temp_hex = OregionTR.mid((z*256)+(x*8)+1280, 6);
            if(temp_hex != "000000")
            {
                temp_hex.append("000");
                HexToInt(temp_hex, temp_int);
                Input("stuff\\regions\\xbox_chunks\\tr\\" + QString::number(temp_int) + ".dat", temp_chunk);

                //... minor file changes

                OTRChunks[(zPos*27) + xPos] = temp_chunk;

                //... minor file changes
            }
        }
    }
}
//index_ptr is my int value. NOW IT SAYS LEVEL_PTR IS 0!
QMessageBox::information(this, "test", QString::number(level_ptr));
if(OregionTL != "Null")
{
    for(int z=0; z <=26; z++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x <=26; x++)
        {
            temp_hex = OregionTL.mid((z*256)+(x*8)+1320, 6);
            if(temp_hex != "000000")
            {
                temp_hex.append("000");
                HexToInt(temp_hex, temp_int);
                Input("stuff\\regions\\xbox_chunks\\tl\\" + QString::number(temp_int) + ".dat", temp_chunk);

                //... minor file changes

                OTLChunks[(zPos*27) + xPos] = temp_chunk;

                //... minor file changes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the variables local or global variables? If they are global, do you shadow (i.e. re-declare) them as local variables in some function? Do you write beyond the boundaries of some array?

Comment: Create a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org) from your program. That way, you do not need to put the source code for a huge program on the web and we can examine the problem more closely.

Comment: To debug you can check, e.g. with some print statement, in which moment your array get zeroed.

Comment: By the way, if you're on a supported platform, a tool such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is invaluable to debug memory problems.

Comment: The variables are declared locally in the .cpp file but used in multiple functions within the same .cpp file.

Comment: And if your platform doesn't have Valgrind, it's probably Visual Studio and even easier: just put a data breakpoint on the `int` variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for variables to be reset if you have a bug in your program. This is called memory corruption and has many many causes.

If you want help with the bug in your program you are going to have to show us the code. Try and produce a smaller version of your program that still has the same or similar problem.

Comment: Okay. I will edit my post with the exact spot I notice it resets.

Comment: Fine, but that's unlikely to the place where the bug is. That kind of problem is hard to track down unless you have a complete program to work with. As I say try and produce a cut down version of your code (that is still a complete program) and post that.

Comment: I added the loop where I notice it resets. I doubt it will help that much since I don't believe it is a syntax error as more as it is a logic mistake.

Comment: Given the code posted the first thing to examine is the `OBLChunks[(zPos*27) + xPos]` expression. Are you sure that `(zPos*27) + xPos` is in bounds for `OBLChunks`?

Comment: Sorry for being away. It turned out that it was out of its bounds. :) It was negative. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

is it possible that you are going out of range? something like

```
 int temp = value_larger_than_MAX_INT;
```

In this case, the value will be truncated so you might see 0, or small numbers instead of very large numbers.
It sounds plausible to me after reading through your code, so consider using unsigned int instead of int, or even long.

hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry it's a month later, but no that's not the issue. I solved the problem in a really stupid way. I just simply made another variable right next to it called something like "int_var2" and used that instead. for some reason, this variable didnt reset....